# Access label of Field Set in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, fieldsets, dynamic-binding

I am using Field Set in Visualforce pages to render user-defined fields.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="HARDCODED TITLE">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fieldsets.SystemFields}"
       ....
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Instead of giving the enclosing section a hard-coded title I would like to dynamically reference / display the Field Sets Label like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$ObjectType.Account.fieldsets.SystemFields.Label}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fieldsets.SystemFields}"
       ....
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

This is not possible as the variable exposes a FieldSetMember Array. **Is there any workaround (without additional Controller code) or an Idea to vote for?**

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but I just worked on my solution for this and wanted to share.
There is not solution without controller code that I can find but here's one with minimal additions.

## Getting a single fieldset name

To get the name of a single fieldset you can create a variable in the controller:

```
public String fieldSetName { get; set; }
```

then in the constructor you could use:

```
fieldSetName = Schema.SObjectType.Case.fieldSets.getMap().get('fieldSetApiName').getLabel();
```

and finally in the VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="{!fieldSetName}">
```

## Multiple fieldsets

If you are working with multiple field sets my solution has been to create a map of titles.

```
public Map<String,String> fieldSetNames { get; set; }
```

Then use a function you can call from the constructor.

```
public void loadFieldsSetMap(){
    Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fsMap = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fieldSets.getMap();
    fieldSetNames = new Map<String, String>();
    for(String i : fsMap.keySet() ){
        fieldSetNames.put(i, fsMap.get(i).getLabel());      
    }
}
```

In the page I then call the relevant map entry with the name **in lowercase**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="{!fieldSetNames['fieldsetapiname']}">
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fieldsets.fieldSetApiName}"
   ....
</apex:repeat>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hard coded value I would use custom label.

Comment: your answer is appreciated, however in order to be of value to the person looking for the answer you should qualify it with a why and how.