# Get FieldSet label on VisualForce page via apex for custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, fieldsets, label

I am creating a VisualForce (VF) page as PDF as report for a custom object `MyCustomObject` supporting different languages. Therefore I want to retrieve the label of a FieldSet, to dynamically account for different languages depending on user settings.

I found [Access label of Field Set in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64075/access-label-of-field-set-in-visualforce) which doesn't seem to work for custom objects.

**Fieldset MyFieldSet**

I created a fieldset for my `MyCustomObject` object, added a few fields and translated the FieldSetLabel to different languages.

```
label=MyFieldSetLabel
ApiName=MyFieldSetApiName
Fields=[...]
```

**VF page - hardcoded fieldset label**

This example uses a hard coded title for a block section header, not accounting for langugage differences

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="HARDCODED TITLE">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.fieldsets.MyFieldSet}"
       ....
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**VF page - dynamic fieldset label**

Aim is a dynamic section tatle based on FieldSetLabel, accounting for translations.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.fieldsets.MyFieldSet.Label}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fieldsets.MyFieldSet}"
       ....
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Since I am able to create translations for my FieldSetLabel it must be possible to dynamically access it. When creating VF pages with multi-langugage support, you cannot rely on a hard-coded fieldset title.

Any idea how to retrieve a FieldSet label via apex on a VisualForce page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve it dynamically using DescribeSObjectResult like below.

In Apex controller:

```
public String getFieldSetLabel() {

    String objectName = 'Your object API Name';
    String fieldSetName = 'Your fieldset API Name';
    Schema.SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = objectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.FieldSet> fieldSetMap = objectDescribe.fieldSets.getMap();
    Schema.FieldSet fieldSet = fieldSetMap.get(fieldSetName);
    String fieldSetLabel = fieldSet.getLabel();
    return fieldSetLabel;
}
```

In Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="{!fieldSetLabel}">
```

Comment: Do I have to place this in a controller? Adding it inline doesn't seem to work: `<apex:pageBlockSection title="{!Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('MyCustomObject__c').getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap().get('MyFieldSet').getLabel()}" />` results in `Unknwon function Schmea.getGlobalDescribe. Check spelling.`

Comment: Yes it needs to be in Apex controller. Please see my edit.